# Reboot issues on ubuntu 20.04.2 Kernel 5.8.0-45-generic

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04

Disclaimer- New to Ubuntu

I recently migrated from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. I have downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.2 iso from the official site, wiped the whole disk and installed the OS. It worked fine on the 1st day, later there were issues with wifi network - super slow internet and unable to connect to 5GHz network. Spent whole day trying to fix this, but nothing seemed to work. I tried to reboot and then I got stuck with blank screen. I tried few online solutions which uses GRUB cmd, none of them worked. Then I tried booting the earlier version of kernel **5.8.0-44-generic**, it worked and also there seems to be no issues with network as well . I have made this as my default for time being, but I want to understand why this is happening.

Also, another question, I see that the latest kernel available as of now is 5.11 [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) but its not installed in mine, is it because its not yet available as part of LTS release? Should I try installing newer kernels?

**Hardware:**

1. Lenovo Legion Y540
2. Nvidia GTX 1660Ti

Comment: 5.11 is not in general use yet. Expect it to be in the soon to be released 21.04 LTS. I would suggest you not updated your system but of course it is up to you.  April 22, 2021
Ubuntu 21.04 is due for release on April 22, 2021. It will become the latest stable release of Ubuntu, succeeding Ubuntu 20.10 which was released last October.

Comment: The `/var/log/boot.log.X` (boot time should be the first line) may provide a clue as to where the boot was failing. Could also review the syslog, dmesg and/or kern.log files in /var/log for times when you were having issues to see if there are any messages of interest.